# Is there a term that means "closed under conjugation and multiplication"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

For a group $G$, I am working with subsets $I\subset G$ which are closed under multiplication (with elements of $I$) and conjugation (with elements of $G$).  Is there a name for such subsets?  I was thinking normal subgroup, but that requires being closed under inverses too...

Comment: Are you referring specifically to $G$ a group?

Comment: Yes; post updated.

Comment: Such $I$ should be  called a "normal subsemigroup" (if it is also closed under the inversion then it would be a normal subgroup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessed that such a thing would be called an **invariant sub-semigroup**, and it turns out [that is a thing.](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Invariant_subset)